# How to draw a image using C# grapics class

Tags: c#, .net, drawimage

I want to draw a image using using C# graphics class using provided X,Y coordinates and zoom Value. I tried to do this but it is not giving me the correct result.

```
Stream originalStream = ImageHelper.UrlToImageStream(list1.FirstOrDefault().OriginalImageUrl);

var bmp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

int width = 0;
int height = 0;

var img = new Bitmap(bmp,
                    (int)(bmp.Size.Width / zoomLevel),
                    (int)(bmp.Size.Height / zoomLevel));

var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

g.DrawString(Text, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.White, new Rectangle((int)CurrentTextX, (int)CurrentTextY, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle((int)CurrentX, (int)CurrentY, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting nothing or is what you are getting wrong somehow? Please, give us something more to work with.

Comment: One problem I see right off the bat is var bmp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height); Can you use bmp while you're declaring it?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void mapPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\img.png");
    g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(10,10,img.Width/zoomLevel, img.Height/zoomLevel);
}
```

Try it like this also what is the incorrect result you are getting right now?